# How to call correctly getopt function

Tags: c++, argv, getopt

Errors while calling int getopt function from http://code.google.com/p/darungrim/source/browse/trunk/ExtLib/XGetopt.cpp?r=17

```
`check.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:`
```

`check.cpp:14:55: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char**’ to ‘char* const*’ [-fpermissive]`

`/usr/include/getopt.h:152:12: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘int getopt(int, char* const*, const char*)’ [-fpermissive]`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#ifdef USE_UNISTD
#include <unistd.h>
#else
#include "XGetopt.h"
#endif
using namespace std;

int main() {

string text="-f  input.gmn -output.jpg";
int argc=text.length();
cout<<"argc: "<<argc<<endl;
char const * argv = text.c_str();
cout<<"argv: "<<argv<<endl;
int c = getopt (argc, &argv, "f:s:o:pw:h:z:t:d:a:b:?");
cout<<"c: "<<c<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing two things here:

1. Argument list is not a string. It is a list of strings. Don't get confused by shell or other programs that ask for a list of arguments as a single string. At the end of day, those programs would split a string into arrays of arguments and run an executable (see [execv](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html), for example).
2. There is always an implicit first argument in argument list that is a program name.

Here is your code, fixed:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    const char *argv[] = { "ProgramNameHere",
                           "-f", "input.gmn", "-output.jpg" };
    int argc = sizeof(argv) / sizeof(argv[0]);
    std::cout << "argc: " << argc << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        std::cout << "argv: "<< argv[i] << std::endl;
    int c;

    while ((c = getopt(argc, (char **)argv, "f:s:o:pw:h:z:t:d:a:b:?")) != -1) {
        std::cout << "Option: " << (char)c;
        if (optarg)
            std::cout << ", argument: " << optarg;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much for the solution! My problem is, that I am building command line tool and at the beginning whole line is a string. How could I convert `string text="-f  input.gmn -output.jpg";` into `const char *argv[] = { "ProgramNameHere",
                           "-f", "input.gmn", "-output.jpg" };`

Comment: @user1020174: I recommend you ask a separate question as for how do you split a string.

Comment: Oh please, just simply answer "inserting that much needed '(char **)' before 'argv' parameter argument in getopt_long().